# CouchBase .NET API -- set key, value for a specific bucket

Tags: c#, couchbase

I am writing a wrapper api to provide a Set method, something similar to:

```
Set(string bucket, string key, object value)
```

What I need is, if a supplied bucket is not available -- I need to use default bucket, otherwise Store it to specific bucket.

One way I can think of is to instantiate the CouchbaseClient with supplied bucket inside a try...catch block and if that fails Store it in *default* bucket. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you don't want to instantiate a client-per-request.  The overhead of connecting to the cluster the first time is not trivial.  It's therefore recommended that you create a static instance per bucket, per app domain.  A client has bucket affinity as well, so you can't switch buckets without reinstantiating the client.

For information on configuring multiple buckets, see http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Couchbase+.NET+Client+Library.

If you create multiple bucket config sections as per above, you could have your method be something like:

```
private static Dictionary<string, CouchbaseClient> _clientDict = new Dictionary<string, CouchbaseClient>();

public IStoreResult Set(string key, object value, string bucketName, string bucketPassword = "") 
{
    if (! _clientDict.ContainsKey(bucketName))
    {
        _clientDict[bucketName] = new CouchbaseClient(bucketName); //assume this matches the config section name
    }

   return _clientDict[bucketName].ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, key, value);
}
```

I haven't actually run this code, but something like this should work.  Just remember you'd have to have a matching config section.  So using the wiki example, you'd have two keys in your dictionary - "bucket-a" and "bucket-b."

The next release of the client will support querying for buckets over the REST API, but that would impact performance a touch.  Those bits should drop as Developer Preview 4 shortly.  In that case, you will be able to add a call to the new CouchbaseCluster object's ListBuckets method and check for a bucket in the return list.  If that bucket exists, you could cache its associated CouchbaseClient.